# Getting text from Qt WebView using Javascript

Tags: javascript, qt, text, webview, qml

Is it possible to get the text from a page loaded in WebView in QT using either javascript or qml? All of the answers I have found have been in Java or something that isn't similar to QT.

Comment: Eventually you can use ```javaScriptWindowObjects```

Comment: Could you specify which version of Qt you're using?  The answer will depend on that.

Comment: Qt 5.3.1, (Qt Creator 3.1.2)

Answer (score 2):

In Qt5, most of the WebView functionality became part of the undocumented (and unsupported) QtWebKit.experimental.  The most comprehensive explanation of these features I've found [is this blog post](http://rschroll.github.io/beru/2013/08/21/qtwebview.experimental.html).

Before proceeding, a word of caution: the experimental features can -- and will -- change in future versions.  Because of this you will see a warning in the console when running the sample code.

Here's a full example that posts the entire HTML to the console.  It should be fairly trivial to change this to only dump part of the page, to send the HTML elsewhere, etc.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtWebKit 3.0
import QtWebKit.experimental 1.0

Rectangle {
    width: 800
    height: 600

    WebView {
        url: "http://stackoverflow.com/"
        anchors.fill: parent

        // Enable communication between QML and WebKit
        experimental.preferences.navigatorQtObjectEnabled: true;

        // When the document loads, post the outerHTML back to the QML layer.
        onLoadingChanged: {
            if (loadRequest.status === WebView.LoadSucceededStatus) {
                experimental.evaluateJavaScript(
                    "navigator.qt.postMessage(document.documentElement.outerHTML)");
            }
        }

        // When we get the message, dump the string data to the console.
        experimental.onMessageReceived: {
            console.log(message.data);
        }
    }
}
```

To summarize, here's what this code is doing:

- Loads Stack Overflow's home page into a WebView instance
- When the page is fully loaded, it asks WebView to evaluate Javascript that reads the outerHTML property of the document and posts this as a message back to QML
- When the message is received, it dumps that HTML to the console